# Preventing a DIV from going below the fold

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a HTML like like so:

```
<div id="window">
  <p>Random length of text</p>
  <p>Random length of text</p>
  <p>Random length of text</p>
  <div id="comment"> input ...</div>
</div>
```

The text is random. What I would like to do is if the id="comment" is ever scrolled off the page, below the fold for example, then I want to add a class "fixed" so I can ensure that id="comment is always visible on the page.

I tried something like this, but it isn't working... Ideas?

```
$('#comment').offset().top  
$('window').scrollTop()
```

Thaks

Comment: On every jQuery API Documentation page like http://api.jquery.com/animate/ they load the user comments only after you scrolled down to them. Maybe you can find it out there how to check this!

Comment: And they do poll check  the scroll state: http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/150705-window-scroll-detection

Comment: Will you inform us if you've found a solution? Would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean that you want the comment div to be stuck to the bottom of the screen independent of the user's scrolling? Because that can be done with just CSS i.e.

```
#comment {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Or maybe you want it to stick to the bottom of the paragraphs, IF they dont fill the full height of the screen? In which case you could use jQuery to dynamically set the above CSS rules depending on the position of the comment div i.e.

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    bottom = $("#comment").position().top + $("#comment").height();
    if (bottom > $(window).height()) $("#comment").addClass("fixed-bottom");
});
```

CSS

```
.fixed-bottom {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the positioning of the Comment block absolute http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_position.asp and you can put it whereever you want on the page. You can then bind to scroll events to reposition it when people change the page.

Comment: thanks but i don't want it to be absolute, I want it to be on the page naturally, and only be fixed when scrolled off the page.

Comment: Then I suggest you add two of them... One that is hidden when the normal one is shown, and when the normal one is out of view, you copy the html from the normal one to the fixed one and display the fixed one.

Comment: It will be even worse if you remove the existing object from the DOM. Then you might end up in a loop where it is going out of sight, your script triggers making it an absolete positioned element. That action then makes space on the page that makes your element come into view again, and you reverse... After which it is invisible again... Endless loop